# Multiple Regression, Normal distribution and Normalization

Tags: normal-distribution, multiple-regression, normalization

I am trying to run a Multiple Regression model but I am not sure what should I do to prepare the data input. In my model the dependent variable is the artificial surfaces in hectares, the independent are the GDP (monetary value) and Population (inhabitants). The histogram shows that the data is not normal distributed.

1. I would like to know if I need to normalize the distribution of the data in order to get the "bell" curve and/or
2. if I need to normalize the data (with the max-min or standardize).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding 1) No, you don't. OLS regression makes assumptions about the error from the model, as estimated by the residuals, not about the variables.

Regarding 2) You don't *have* to; opinions vary about whether results are more interpretable on standardized data or on the raw data. I think the latter is usually more interpretable, but others disagree.